# Amplify AppSync doesn't upload S3Object file from client

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, graphql, aws-amplify, aws-appsync

First, when the docs at https://aws-amplify.github.io/docs/js/api#complex-objects say:

```
input CreateTodoInput {
  id: ID
  name: String!
  description: String
  file: S3ObjectInput # This input type will be generated for you
}
```

I get an error `Type "S3ObjectInput" not found in document.` and I have to add `S3ObjectInput` manually.

This is my schema (the docs are not very clear on it so I put it together from similar questions)

```
type Picture @model {
  id: ID!
  file: S3Object!
  url: String!
  rating: Int
  appearedForRanking: Int
}

type S3Object {
  bucket: String!
  key: String!
  region: String!
}

input CreatePictureInput {
  id: ID
  file: S3ObjectInput!
  url: String!
  rating: Int
  appearedForRanking: Int
}

input S3ObjectInput {
  bucket: String!
  region: String!
  localUri: String
  visibility: Visibility
  key: String
  mimeType: String
}

enum Visibility {
  public
  protected
  private
}
```

And this is the client code (with React)

```
class PictureUpload extends Component {

  state = { fileUrl: '', file: '', filename: '' }

  handleChange = e => {
    let file = e.target.files[0]
    let filext = file.name.split('.').pop()
    let filename = uuid() + '.' + filext

    this.setState({
      fileUrl: URL.createObjectURL(file),
      filename: filename
    })
  }

  saveFile = async () => {
    let visibility = 'public'

    let fileObj = {
      bucket: awsConfig.aws_user_files_s3_bucket,
      region: awsConfig.aws_user_files_s3_bucket_region,
      key: visibility + '/' + this.state.filename,
      mimeType:'image/jpeg',
      localUri: this.state.fileUrl,
      visibility: visibility
    }

    try {
      const picture = await API.graphql(
        graphqlOperation(mutations.createPicture, {
          input: {
            url: this.state.filename,
            file: fileObj
          }
        })
      )
```

The problem is that the mutation runs without errors, setting the DB records, but the file does not appear in S3. The docs say `the SDK uploads the file to Amazon S3 for you.` so I don't think I forgot to add something.

Any idea why the upload doesn't happen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Automatic upload of file to S3 happens only if using the `aws-appsync` package, with `aws-amplify` you need to upload the file yourself using `Storage.put(...)`.

This [GitHub issue](https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-js/issues/3794#issuecomment-519226508) explain the differences in more detail

Answer (score 0):

For ReactNative I've found that you can't simply provide a uri, but rather a blob. Try this code instead:

```
const response = await fetch(uri);
const blob = await response.blob();

let file = {
  bucket,
  key,
  region,
  localUri: blob,
  mimeType,
};
```

This should get the image data to S3 as long as your authentication is properly configured.